# Adding parameters to the event sent with gtag method with GTM(Google Tag Manager)

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I have a code sent from the website infrastructure as follows. However, "currency" and "value" parameters in Google suggestions are not sent. Can I add "value" and "currency" parameters to this event with gtm? Or is there another method?

```
gtag("event", "view_item", {
    items: {
      item_id: "23233",
      item_name: "BenQ PD2705Q 27-inch QHD,USB-C",
      currency: "TRY",
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Benq",
      item_category: "Kurgu ve tasarım monitörü",
      price: 19589.3,
      quantity: 1
    }
})
```

That is, the event must be sent to GA4 as follows.

```
gtag("event", "view_item", {
    currency: "TRY",
    value: 19589.3,
    items: {
      item_id: "23233",
      item_name: "BenQ PD2705Q 27-inch QHD,USB-C",
      currency: "TRY",
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Benq",
      item_category: "Kurgu ve tasarım monitörü",
      price: 19589.3,
      quantity: 1
    }
})
```

Comment: The formatting is diffrent with gtm [view_item-gtm](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#view_item-gtm)

Comment: i think it's not totally different, if i just use gtm, yes i need to use dataLayer method.
But I want to know can I add any parameter with gtm? (to the event sent with gtag method)

Comment: It is not suggestion. They are required parameters for ecommerce event. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#view_item